# Creating drive time polygon around map point?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, software-recommendations, google-fusion-tables

I'd like to create a 30 min drive time polygon around 400 separate points I have plotted to google maps.

I have discovered http://www.freemaptools.com/how-far-can-i-travel.htm but this seems to freak when you get near the sea (many of my points are).

And also http://cartoo.dyndns.org/ which works well, but I can't then extract the polygons in .KML form.

Anyone come across any tools able to help me?

Answer (score 6):

check out this example [here](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/gmaps/samples/geoprocessor/gp_servicearea.html) which uses arcgis service time geoprocessing service and google maps.

if your points locate in US, u can use CreateDriveTimePolygons from ESRI [here](http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/ESRI_DriveTime_US/GPServer/CreateDriveTimePolygons/execute). you need to do is that write Input Location, Drive Times and format as json then execute your process.

beside this you should check out similar ques.:

1. Creating drive time polygons using open source tools, [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/creating-drive-time-polygons-using-open-source-tools)
2. Can you make a travel region polygon with with Google Maps API?, [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46/can-you-make-a-travel-region-polygon-with-with-google-maps-api)

Example Input Location:

```
{features:[{geometry:{x:-117.36539840698242,y:33.99945042078996,spatialReference:
           {wkid:4326}}}],spatialReference:{wkid:4326}}
```

[image]

Comment: Works for Canada too.

Comment: My points are all Australian based. Very low knowledge of code - just want to take a tool like Cartoo and extract into KML so I can combined 400 data points onto one single map.

Comment: This worked well but unfortunately the ESRI service tops out at 15 minute drive times - wish it went to 20 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

There is the Route360 API that also works with Google Maps.
https://developers.route360.net/index.html

It offers quiet a few functionalities. Including different modes of transportation or the intersection of polygons

[image: transit routing Berlin]

As well you can add a few hundred points at once and see the result:

[image: multi point travel times]

It works for most countries in Europe and North America

Comment: Unfortunately their layer output is SVG and they make you pay to export GeoJSON (403 errors whenever you try to run a GeoJSON example locally). Since I'm using Google MyMaps this doesn't work for me without some hacking.

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer: I work for iGeolise**

You can use the TravelTime API to draw maps based on drive times [here](http://www.traveltimeplatform.com/travel-time-maps/), it works for location-based searches (for consumer-facing sites for example) or one off maps.

This example is for drive times from Norwich, UK. There are multiple polygons for 15 minute intervals from 15 mins - 1 hour, starting at midday. It uses lat/ long points translated onto the map. If it's just the data you need, it can also extract postcodes from the area in a list rather than a visual map format.
[image: Norwich drive times]

Answer (score 2):

I know this post was from a while ago, but we ran into the same problem so we went off and built it as a premium service for our Google Maps enterprise offering. Needless to say it is a paid solution, so I am not going into a marketing pitch on a technical forum.

However, this was one of the first posts that I found when I was actually looking fora solution even if I had to pay for it... I didn't want an ESRI server, so we setup a OSM server with road networks and use pgRouting on top and then packaged it up as a web service for those who are interested how we built it. I am happy to share more details if you prefer to build something similar rather than licensing it: http://cmapsanalytics.com/drivetime.html