# trying to find areas within a certain driving distance along a road network WITHOUT a specific destination

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, network-analyst

I'm trying to use Arcmap 10.1 to find all the areas along a road network (a county roads layer in this case) that are a certain driving distance from a single origin point. In essence, this would be akin to a service area analysis, except there is only a single facility used rather than a whole list.

Applicability: trying to find where a subject could move to within the county (using census block layers) if they want to live no more than, for instance, an hour's drive from work/school/etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to draw a polygon where its vertices are determined as 1 hour driving from a specific point, then do a cut of the road layers that are within that polygon, and then determine what the map looks like?

Comment: Drive Time Polygons? see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31057/create-drive-time-polygon-around-a-map-point

Comment: Live Example (Google Maps v2 with Esri Network Analysis) http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/gmaps/samples/geoprocessor/gp_servicearea.html

Answer (score 1):

This **is** a service area analysis. You are not *required* to use more than one origin or multiple break values in the service area analysis solver. You can generate a polygon, detailed or not - the only thing to watch (since you mention county) is that any area completely surrounded by a road will be included, which may lead to misleading polygons depending on break values and just how rural the county is. See [Check/Uncheck Trim Polygon option in Network Analyst](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93603/check-uncheck-trim-polygon-option-in-network-analyst/93620#93620) for more info.