# Determine 3 and 6 minute fire response times

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, network-analyst, time

I'm expecting to get an Excel file with data on previous fire and emergency response times. I was told it will have incident addresses and the response time for each incident (~ 12K incidents). I also have a street layer and an address layer. Some streets have speed limit data, some don't, although I can assign arbitrary values based on road class (collector, major arterial, local, etc.).

Is this sufficient data to produce a map showing response times? Ideally there would be a city-wide map similar to what an outside vendor produced 5 years ago, which to me looks more like a sort of heat map. They'd also like maps for each of eight fire stations. They're sort of unclear on exactly what they want; they may not know. I think essentially what they want is a map for each station showing 3 and 6 minute response time zones based on their actual data. I could do a multiple ring buffer based on an average speed, but that doesn't take into account actual streets. All help appreciated, thanks.

Running ArcInfo 10.0 sp5, have Network Analyst and Spatial Analyst, although a bit rusty on both.

Comment: With the Network Analysis extension "Drive time Polygons" http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31057/create-drive-time-polygon-around-a-map-point

Comment: Hmm, never heard of that one, will check it out, thanks.

Comment: This example is a little slow (using Google Maps API v2 and Esri) click a point on the map and wait http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/gmaps/samples/geoprocessor/gp_servicearea.html

Comment: It would be interesting to see if there are significant differences in the rush hour / non-rush hour incidents and resulting response time maps.

Comment: Was this ever solved such that an answer could be posted? Because it looks like an interesting problem in that you have *actual* (incident location and recorded) response times to compare against *predicted* (network service area) response times.

Comment: It was solved, but that was at a previous job, so I don't have the solution currently, sorry.

Comment: Quite alright. I think @mapperz could probably turn his comment into an acceptable answer along with the Service Area Solver in Network Analyst.