# Create circles around a point on a map measuring the radius in hours

Tags: google-maps, distance, intersection, time, road

Disclaimer: I am not experienced in GIS and hope this question fits in this category.

I was wondering whether it is somehow possible to create a circle* around a city, using Google Maps or the like, whilst the circle is not measured in miles (or other distance measure) but in hours of driving.

The background is the following: I am looking for an ideal location to live if I have to commute between two different places. Ideally one place should be within a ~15 minute range and the other place in a ~45 minute range. I can't find an intersection manually. If there is an automated way how to do this, I could experiment with my parameters to find the ideal place.

Any ideas?

*Obviously it won't result in a circle.

Comment: Hours is a function of distance and speed. You're basically looking for drive time polygons. To do this with any accuracy or detail, you'd need a network to analyze on since straight distances won't be the same as driving on roads. While this can be done in GIS with the right data and tools, since you're looking for a Google Maps type solution there are already some options provided at this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31057/create-drive-time-polygon-around-a-map-point?rq=1 There are also several other linked questions (right side of the page) there with more posibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else needs a tool that does what I was looking for:

http://openrouteservice.org/

This will do the trick.