# Getting 15 minutes Travel time polygon from point (lat, long) using Google Road API?

Tags: google-maps, isochrone

Given a location specified as latitude/longitude, I want to know how to obtain a polygon feature that represents 15 minutes' travelling time from the original point location, using the Google Maps API.

Comment: I think this may actually be a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46/can-you-make-a-travel-region-polygon-with-with-google-maps-api?rq=1 but while that question is targetted at Google Maps, all the answers treat it like a software recommendation question, and it's (IMO, wrongly) closed as too-broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key term you need to search for this is **"[isochrone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isochrone_map)"**, meaning a line/area representing space where something arrives or occurs in equal time. You can find related questions: [isochrone](/questions/tagged/isochrone).

Producing isochrones of driving time with the Google Maps API is technically possible. There are several attempts:

- https://github.com/sandropaganotti-zz/isochrone-with-google-map (out of date, but illustrative)
- https://github.com/dugwood/isochrone-isodistance-with-google-maps (a working example)

The second link includes an example of using their interface:

```js
isochrone.compute({
    lat: 48.860901,
    lng: 2.307405,
    type: 'duration',
    value: 10 * 60,
    mode: 'walking',
    callback: myCallback
});
```

It's worth noting that this is not computing *true* isochrones. Rather it is using the [distance matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) to sample travel times across an area, and then estimate a round-ish shape that approximates an isochrone. Google does not currently support direct computation of isochrones with their API.

There are other services that return better isochrones, such as Mapbox's [isochrone API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#isochrone). Many such substitutes are listed as answers to this question: [Can you make a travel region polygon with with Google Maps API?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46/can-you-make-a-travel-region-polygon-with-with-google-maps-api)

Comment: If you provide additional details regarding the isochrones and my question it will be helpful and can we use isochrones in javascript or node.js

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar Maybe you could add more details in your question? How is your application currently put together? Is this for the browser, or a server? Have you read the readmes of those Github repositories?

Comment: IT is server side application for nodejs and javascript

Comment: Mapbox IsoChrone API seems pretty good - https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/get-started-isochrone-api/#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Although I see I am late to the party, I would share my thoughts with you on creating proper isochrones.
If you are familiar with PostgreSQL, PosGIS, pgRouting and OSM you could create a nice tool that creates isochrones.

Given PostgreSQL and its extensions, PostGIS and pgRouting are installed on your server you'll first need to import a road network for your area of interest that you can get from OSM.

You will then utilize the routing algorithm of your preference in pgRouting.

A sample query (that I grabbed from a presentation PDF) is below:

```
SELECT 1 As id, ST_SetSRID(pgr_pointsAsPolygon(     $$SELECT dd.seq ASid, ST_X(v.the_geom) AS x, ST_Y(v.the_geom) As y FROM pgr_drivingDistance($sub$SELECT gid Asid, source, target,             cost_s AScost, reverse_cost_s AS reverse_cost FROM ospr.ways$sub$,        (SELECTn.idFROM ospr.ways_vertices_pgr ASnORDERBY ST_SetSRID(                ST_Point(­76.933399,38.890703),4326) <­> n.the_geom LIMIT1)         ,  5*60, true      ) AS dd INNERJOIN ospr.ways_vertices_pgr AS v ON dd.node = v.id$$   ), 4326) As geom;
```

If this is something that you are interested in, you can find more details around page 11 of this PDF
[Ten problems solved by PostGIS](http://postgis.us/presentations/PGConfUS2017_PostGISTop10.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the reachability data from Openrouteservices.org and put them into GoogleMyMaps interactive map builder.

http://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/how-to-make-isochrone-map-in-google-mymaps-quickly/